# Creating a new view or table from the last record

Tags: sql-server, view, clustered-index

I have 2 tables DraftProducts and Products.

The only difference between the 2 tables is the "phase" field.

I have productCode varchar(20), phase(tinyint), Name, Price, SpecialCells.... etc fields in my DraftProducts table.

the last phase is actually 1 record in the Product table for me.

Until now, when 1 user said that the draft work was finished, I was automatically recording the last phase in the Product table.

But when the last draft changes, it needs to be updated again. It needs to be deleted when deleted etc. a lot of additional work is going on.

In my database, some tables work from the DraftProducts table and some tables from the Products table.

But can I do this as "Products view" independent of the user?

How can I create a "ProductsView" with max(phase) 1 record? How should I do group by or distinct?

As a result of this table, the Products table or view I want should be like this.

p1=8 price, category, description etc.
p2=15 price, category, description etc.
p3=22 price, category, description etc.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DraftProducts](
    [productCode] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [phase] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [category] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [description] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [price] float NULL
)
```

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [DraftProductsIndex1] ON [dbo].[DraftProducts]
(
    [productCode] ASC,
    [phase] ASC
)
```

```
insert into DraftProducts (productCode,phase,name)
values 
('p1',1,'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'),
('p2',2,'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'),
('p3',1,'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'),
('p2',15,'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb'),
('p3',22,'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb'),
('p1',8,'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb'),
('p2',7,'ccccccccccccccc')
```

```
7 rows affected
```

```
select * from DraftProducts 

/*
finish phase
p1=8
p2=15
p3=22
*/
```

| productCode | phase | name | category | description | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| p1 | 1 | aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| p1 | 8 | bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| p2 | 15 | bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| p2 | 2 | aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| p2 | 7 | ccccccccccccccc | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| p3 | 1 | aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| p3 | 22 | bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb | *null* | *null* | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/VIFnALEa)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is a [window function](https://www.sqlshack.com/use-window-functions-sql-server/), particularly a ranking window function such as [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) like so:

```
WITH _DraftProductsSorted AS
(
    SELECT 
        productCode,
        phase,
        [name],
        category,
        [description],
        price,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER -- Generates a unique sequential ID within each partition of productCode sorted by the phase
        (
            PARTITION BY productCode 
            ORDER BY phase DESC
        ) AS PartitionSortId
    FROM DraftProducts
)

SELECT 
    productCode,
    phase,
    [name],
    category,
    [description],
    price
FROM _DraftProductsSorted
WHERE PartitionSortId = 1; -- Only return the latest row of each productCode
```

All you have to do is slap that inside a view, e.g. `ProductsView`, and anytime the `phase` changes for a particular `productCode` the view will automatically show the latest version.

Window functions are very helpful for solving a number of problems. I highly suggest reading through the links I provided. Other window functions like the value functions such as `FIRST_VALUE()` and `LAST_VALUE()` can also be used as an alternative way to solve your problem, but would've required more code and I think would've been less performant than the solution I provided above using `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Speaking of performance, while I doubt you'll have any issues as is, if you want to make a slight change to your clustered index like the following, it'll be slightly more suitable to the solution I provided above:

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [DraftProductsIndex1] ON [dbo].[DraftProducts]
(
    [productCode] ASC,
    [phase] DESC
);
```

Notice I changed the order it persists `phase` to `DESC` (descending) so it exactly matches the `ORDER BY` clause of the `ROW_NUMBER()` function in my solution above.

Comment: That's how I made it a view. Thank you.
[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DhPuwzZU)

Comment: @omerix Great, no problem!